# how to build an object [key, value] use string got form page

Tags: javascript

I want get two element from page and put into one object

```
const entryElements = await page.$$('div.kpi-entry');
const contents = await Promise.all(
entryElements.map(async (element) => {
  const objValue= await (await element.$('span.text-xl'))?.innerText();
  const objKey= await (await element.$('eui-base-v0-tooltip'))?.innerText();
  const kpiObject = {objValue,objKey,};
  return obj;
})
```

);

obj returns

```
  { objValue: '1', objKey: 'A' },
  { objValue: '2', objKey: 'B' },
  { objValue: '3', objKey: 'C' },
  { objValue: '4', objKey: 'D' },
  { objValue: '5', objKey: 'E' }
```

but I expected

```
{
  A: '1',
  B: '2',
  C: '3',
  D: '4',
  E: '5',
}
```

what is the best wat to do this

Comment: `Object.fromEntries([[objKey, objVal], ...])`

Comment: @pilchard  there is EROR "Expression expected",  should I add some function after ... ?

Answer (score 0):

I only adapted your own code, you should check [MDN Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) for more details.

```js
const entryElements = await page.$$('div.kpi-entry');
const newObject = {};
const contents = await Promise.all(
entryElements.forEach(async (element) => {
  const objValue= await (await element.$('span.text-xl'))?.innerText();
  const objKey= await (await element.$('eui-base-v0-tooltip'))?.innerText();
  newObject[objKey] = objValue;
})

console.log(newObject)
```

Comment: thank you again, but  newObject[objKey] = objValue;  here have error code cannot be run

Comment: Which error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = [
  { objValue: "1", objKey: "A" },
  { objValue: "2", objKey: "B" },
  { objValue: "3", objKey: "C" },
  { objValue: "4", objKey: "E" },
  { objValue: "5", objKey: "F" },
];

let map = obj.map(element => {
  return { [element.objKey]: element.objValue };
});
console.log(Object.assign(...map));
```